# redux-form How to have initial value in the input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I use `redux-form` for my form, following the example: https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/docs/api/fields.md/

So the `<Fields />` is like so:

```
<Fields
  names={['firstName', 'lastName']}
  component={input}
  validate={{
    firstName: (value, allValues, props, name) => 'error'
  }}
  warn={{
    lastName: (value, allValues, props) => 'warning'
  }}
/>
```

**the fields component that i render is this**

```
const renderFields = (fields) => (
  <div>
    <div className="input-row">
      <input {...fields.firstName.input} type="text"/>
      {fields.firstName.meta.touched && fields.firstName.meta.error &&
       <span className="error">{fields.firstName.meta.error}</span>}
    </div>
    <div className="input-row">
      <input {...fields.lastName.input} type="text"/>
      {fields.lastName.meta.touched && fields.lastName.meta.error &&
       <span className="error">{fields.lastName.meta.error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

So far so good, the form displays the 2 input fields and i can add values into them.

**But how do i pass default values into the input's ?**

When i add the `value` property into the `input`, i cant edit the input afterwards.

For example, i add the `value` prop with a value like so:

```
const renderFields = (fields) => (
  <div>
    <div className="input-row">
      // add value="my name"
      <input {...fields.firstName.input} type="text" value="my name" />
      {fields.firstName.meta.touched && fields.firstName.meta.error &&
       <span className="error">{fields.firstName.meta.error}</span>}
    </div>
    <div className="input-row">
       // add value="my last name"
      <input {...fields.lastName.input} type="text" value="my last name" />
      {fields.lastName.meta.touched && fields.lastName.meta.error &&
       <span className="error">{fields.lastName.meta.error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

In that way, the inputs have always the same init value.
Any help on how to have default value and also be able to edit it, thank you.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are aware that Redux-Form is deprecated by the author for over three years by now? It says so directly on the start site of the homepage. Generally, nowadays you should [Avoid Putting Form State In Redux](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#avoid-putting-form-state-in-redux).

Comment: Hey, @phry, honestly i was not aware of that. We have an old app that already using redux-form so i didnt check if it is deprecated.  But Thank you for the feedback its very usefull. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you provide the `value` prop you will need to provide `onChange` function as well and handle the state - https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

and from redux-form docs: https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/docs/api/field.md/#-code-onchange-event-newvalue-previousvalue-name-gt-void-code-optional-

Answer (score 1):

You need a state variable to hold the input value.

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
```

In the `input` tag, use the previously declared state variable as `value` & in `onChange` of input, set the input value to the target value.

```
<input type="text" value={inputValue} onChange={e => setInputValue(e.target.value)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use prop defaultValue, as mentioned in Redux Form documentation :https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/api/field.md/#props

```
<Field component={your custom component} defaultValue={}/>
```

Comment: I tried that  but it did not work for me.